# ssh trying to use python2 after I upgraded to 3

Tags: python, monterey

I upgraded to Mac OS 12 a day ago and it has broken a few things for me. Since then I used `brew install python` and `pyenv` to get Python 3.10 running. But now `ssh` doesn't run. Even getting to the help text doesn't work

```
niwa:~ stanton$ ssh -h
dyld[67080]: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.1p1/bin/ssh
  Reason: tried: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python' (no such file)
Abort trap: 6
```

I've changed .bash_profile as per instructions from the Python 3 upgrade and tried with and without the line about Python 2.7. That folder does not exist so I don't know why that was in .bash_profile but everything worked two days ago

```
export PATH="$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"
...
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Comment: Was there some reason in particular you replaced the shipping version of OpenSSH with one from Homebrew?  Monterey ships OpenSSH 8.6.  Presumably whatever is at /usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.1p1/bin/ssh isn't actually the ssh binary.

Comment: Not that I recall, it must have happened a very long time ago or when I installed python via brew yesterday. Anyway, Because of your comment I ran `brew upgrade openssh` and it's working again. Thank you 

Comment: @Craig You can write an "answer" explaining that you had an old version of SSH installed with Brew and updated it to correct this issue, then accept your own answer.

Comment: If you don't need to replace Apple-shipped binaries like OpenSSH, then don't replace them..

Comment: @Ezekiel I can but I think Marc should because he deserves the points. I may have moved to opens in an attempt to get npm to accept our internal root certificate